# Makefile runs but displays missing separator error 12

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I currently have a working directory of C/C++ projects. The directory structure per project is the same: top/include top/src top/Makefile. Whenever I make a new project, I copy and rename a template of this structure. I recently just started a new project and have the same structure and Makefile as another project that works fine. Right now, I only have 3 files: src/Main.c, src/sha256.c, include/sha256.h. sha256.h defines a simple struct and the #ifndef for headers is there as well. sha256.c has a function that prints a word. Main.c includes sha256.h and in main(), prints hello world. My Makefile will compile the code fine. My Makefile also has a rule called "run", which just runs the program. When I run "make run", my program runs and prints out Hello World as I expect but then it spits out the following:

`make: *** [Makefile:50: run] Error 12`

I've checked and double checked and everything that should be tabs are tabs. Also, I copy and pasted this Makefile from another project where this error doesn't occur. I'm completely at a lost. Here's my Makefile

```
TOP = .
SRC_DIR = $(TOP)/src
INC_DIR = $(TOP)/include
OBJ_DIR = $(TOP)/_obj
BIN_DIR = $(TOP)/_bin
TARGET = $(BIN_DIR)/run

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRCS))
DEPS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.d, $(SRCS))
INCLUDES    = -I$(INC_DIR)

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -g

VALGRIND = valgrind

ifeq ($(v), 1)
    VFLAGS = --leak-check=full
else ifeq ($(v), 2)
    VFLAGS = --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
else
    VFLAGS = 
endif

.PHONY: all run valgrind clean gdb

EXTRA_INCLUDES = 
LIBS = -lm
EXTRA_CFLAGS =
CFLAGS += $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(EXTRA_INCLUDES)

all: $(TARGET)

-include $(DEPS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) | $(BIN_DIR)
    @echo "make $(TARGET)"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo " dep $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@)"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -c $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

run:
    @$(TARGET)

valgrind:
    $(VALGRIND) $(VFLAGS) $(TARGET)

gdb:
    gdb $(TARGET)

clean:
    @echo " Cleaning..."
    $(RM) -r $(BIN_DIR)
    $(RM) -r $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Make command outputs:

```
$ make
 dep _obj/Main.d
 dep _obj/sha256.d
make ./_bin/run
$ make run
Hello world
make: *** [Makefile:50: run] Error 12
```

Hexdump using the linux hexdump command:

```
0000000 540a 504f 0909 0909 3d09 2e20 530a 4352
0000010 445f 5249 0909 3d09 2420 5428 504f 2f29
0000020 7273 0a63 4e49 5f43 4944 0952 0909 203d
0000030 2824 4f54 2950 692f 636e 756c 6564 4f0a
0000040 4a42 445f 5249 3d20 2420 5428 504f 2f29
0000050 6f5f 6a62 420a 4e49 445f 5249 3d20 2420
0000060 5428 504f 2f29 625f 6e69 540a 5241 4547
0000070 0954 0909 203d 2824 4942 5f4e 4944 2952
0000080 722f 6e75 0a0a 5253 5343 3d20 2420 7728
0000090 6c69 6364 7261 2064 2824 5253 5f43 4944
00000a0 2952 2a2f 632e 0a29 424f 534a 3d20 2420
00000b0 7028 7461 7573 7362 2074 2824 5253 5f43
00000c0 4944 2952 252f 632e 202c 2824 424f 5f4a
00000d0 4944 2952 252f 6f2e 202c 2824 5253 5343
00000e0 2929 440a 5045 2053 203d 2824 6170 7374
00000f0 6275 7473 2420 5328 4352 445f 5249 2f29
0000100 2e25 2c63 2420 4f28 4a42 445f 5249 2f29
0000110 2e25 2c64 2420 5328 4352 2953 0a29 4e49
0000120 4c43 4455 5345 3d09 2d20 2449 4928 434e
0000130 445f 5249 0a29 430a 2043 203d 6367 0a63
0000140 4643 414c 5347 3d20 2d20 334f 2d20 0a67
0000150 560a 4c41 5247 4e49 2044 203d 6176 676c
0000160 6972 646e 0a0a 6669 7165 2820 2824 2976
0000170 202c 2931 090a 4656 414c 5347 3d20 2d20
0000180 6c2d 6165 2d6b 6863 6365 3d6b 7566 6c6c
0000190 650a 736c 2065 6669 7165 2820 2824 2976
00001a0 202c 2932 090a 4656 414c 5347 3d20 2d20
00001b0 6c2d 6165 2d6b 6863 6365 3d6b 7566 6c6c
00001c0 2d20 732d 6f68 2d77 656c 6b61 6b2d 6e69
00001d0 7364 613d 6c6c 650a 736c 0a65 5609 4c46
00001e0 4741 2053 203d 650a 646e 6669 0a0a 502e
00001f0 4f48 594e 203a 6c61 206c 7572 206e 6176
0000200 676c 6972 646e 6320 656c 6e61 6720 6264
0000210 0a0a 5845 5254 5f41 4e49 4c43 4455 5345
0000220 3d20 0a20 494c 5342 3d20 2d20 6d6c 450a
0000230 5458 4152 435f 4c46 4741 2053 0a3d 4643
0000240 414c 5347 2b20 203d 2824 5845 5254 5f41
0000250 4643 414c 5347 2029 2824 4e49 4c43 4455
0000260 5345 2029 2824 5845 5254 5f41 4e49 4c43
0000270 4455 5345 0a29 610a 6c6c 203a 2824 4154
0000280 4752 5445 0a29 2d0a 6e69 6c63 6475 2065
0000290 2824 4544 5350 0a29 240a 5428 5241 4547
00002a0 2954 203a 2824 424f 534a 2029 207c 2824
00002b0 4942 5f4e 4944 2952 090a 6540 6863 206f
00002c0 6d22 6b61 2065 2824 4154 4752 5445 2229
00002d0 090a 2440 4328 2943 2420 4328 4c46 4741
00002e0 2953 2d20 206f 4024 2420 205e 2824 494c
00002f0 5342 0a29 240a 4f28 4a42 445f 5249 2f29
0000300 2e25 3a6f 2420 5328 4352 445f 5249 2f29
0000310 2e25 2063 207c 2824 424f 5f4a 4944 2952
0000320 090a 6540 6863 206f 2022 6564 2070 2824
0000330 6170 7374 6275 7473 2520 6f2e 252c 642e
0000340 242c 2940 0a22 4009 2824 4343 2029 2824
0000350 4643 414c 5347 2029 4d2d 444d 2d20 2063
0000360 3c24 2d20 206f 4024 0a0a 2824 4942 5f4e
0000370 4944 2952 2420 4f28 4a42 445f 5249 3a29
0000380 090a 6d40 646b 7269 2d20 2070 4024 0a0a
0000390 7572 3a6e 090a 2440 5428 5241 4547 2954
00003a0 0a0a 6176 676c 6972 646e 0a3a 2409 5628
00003b0 4c41 5247 4e49 2944 2420 5628 4c46 4741
00003c0 2953 2420 5428 5241 4547 2954 0a0a 6467
00003d0 3a62 090a 6467 2062 2824 4154 4752 5445
00003e0 0a29 630a 656c 6e61 0a3a 4009 6365 6f68
00003f0 2220 4320 656c 6e61 6e69 2e67 2e2e 0a22
0000400 2409 5228 294d 2d20 2072 2824 4942 5f4e
0000410 4944 2952 090a 2824 4d52 2029 722d 2420
0000420 4f28 4a42 445f 5249 0a29               
000042a
```

Comment: Are you using spaces instead of tabs when saving the file? `make` is *very* picky, all indented lines *must* use tabs, not spaces.

Comment: No, I'm using vscode and for Makefiles it automatically does tabs when I tab inside a Makefile instead of it's usual, insert spaces instead, setting. Also, I've done a search for tabs and tabs show up everywhere they're suppose to.

Comment: What is the exit code of your process? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Missing separator is the typical error when you have space instead of tabs. Have you checked at line 50, to make sure there's no spaces? Even checked in a hex-dump? And which line *is* line 50? Can you please add a comment on it?

Comment: I've tried using make -d and remake -d but besides spitting out the entire Makefile process, they both still end with the same error. According to $? in linux, the exit code is 2, not sure if that helps. If there's a better debugger or better way to go about it, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Line 50 is the line under the "run:" target, "    @$(TARGET)"

Comment: Not the exit code of make, the exit code of the program you're running in the `run` step. Does it actually say missing separator or is that just what you found when you looked up error 12?

Comment: Or just post the make output

Comment: I still see no proof that we're not dealing with a bad indent issue.  have you run a hexdump on the file?

Comment: Copied output from make commands added to question.

Comment: So we stop guessing, please run a hexdump on the makefile and post it.

Comment: @redwards No I haven't, how would I go about that and find what I need to find. Also, I don't think it's an indent problem because I copied the Makefile from another project, at the command line into this new directory and in the other project I don't run into any errors/problems with it. Also, I just added the makefile output when using the commands. The make command still executes, it just prints out the error after.

Comment: *"using vscode and for Makefiles it automatically does tabs"* The way you check that is click in the middle of the blank space before the line, and see where the cursor ends up. If it's placed on the side, then it's truly a tab.

Comment: Your title is misleading, there's no "missing separator" error in the output. It's the program you run that returns `12` (it either have `return 12` in the `main` function, or does `exit(12)` somewhere). Run `make -d run` to get *much* more information about what happens.

Comment: Oh man, I'm sorry guys. I had a missing separator error earlier and it had a 12 in it, I thought that 12 was an error code so when I saw it again I thought it was a make error. Turns out it was an error code with my program that wasn't getting printed out when I ran it just on the command line. Sorry but thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 2):

```
$ make run
Hello world
make: *** [Makefile:50: run] Error 12
```

That is `make` telling you that the program you run exited with the value `12`.

In the program you either have an `exit(12)` call, or a `return 12` statement in the `main` function.

If you run `make` with debug information (`make -d run`) it would be easier to see that.